# Where is output window in Rider?

Tags: jetbrains-ide, rider

I went through the entire app and two Google pages and didn't found it. How can I enable the output window?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If you are referring to build output: As of the latest EAP, you can enable this via:
 Preferences -> Build, Execution, Deployment -> Toolset and Build -> Write log to output

It is disabled by default as of the time of this writing.

[image: [1]]

Answer (score 6):

Currently the build output window available only for not incremental build. We try to add it in next EAP build.

Answer (score 0):

For anyone looking for the "Debug window", it's on View->Tools Windows->Debug and change the mode to "Debugger Output (LLDB)" https://www.jetbrains.com/help/rider/Debug_Tool_Window.html